# jquery animation from current position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the animations to start from the current position of the element, in this case: on the first click from 70% right and on the second click from the position the element is after the animation. (code will be appreciated)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "button" ).click(function(){
             screenWidth = Math.round($("html").width() /2)
      positionLeft = Math.round($(".container").offset().left) 
      
  if ( positionLeft < screenWidth) {  
      $(".container").css('right', "auto");  
     $(".container").animate({
   left: "50%"
   }, 1000);
  } else if (positionLeft == screenWidth) {    
   $(".container").css('left', "auto");
   $(".container").animate({
   right: "50%"
   }, 1000);  
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
  .container{
  background-color:black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%; 
  right :70%;   
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>debugging</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>         
  <button>click</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you wish to animate the `left` selector, so you set right% to auto (leaving left% also at auto), which jumps the element to left margin - where it would be with left/right both set to auto. Then the animation begins.

There are a few ways to solve this. One is to only animate the right selector and not the left (see jsFiddle demo at very bottom of answer).

Another is to swap them around. You just set `right` to auto - which leaves left also at auto. You must set right to auto *and* left to 10% (which is 100-70=30% minus width of container 20%, equals 10%).  I did it this way in the in-answer embedded code to show you that when you switch back to animating the right percentage in the third button click, same problem happens.

Best solution is to just animate everything using one selector, left or right. Choose one and stick with it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "button" ).click(function(){
             screenWidth = Math.round($("html").width() /2)
      positionLeft = Math.round($(".container").offset().left) 
      
  if ( positionLeft < screenWidth) {  
      $(".container").css({'right':"auto", 'left':'10%'});  
     $(".container").animate({
   left: "50%"
   }, 1000);
  } else if (positionLeft == screenWidth) {    
   $(".container").css({'left':"auto", 'right':'30%'});
   $(".container").animate({
   right: "50%"
   }, 1000);  
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
  .container{
  background-color:black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%; 
  right :70%;   
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>debugging</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>         
  <button>click</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

---

And here it is animated just using the right selector: [**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/85bwr8hn/1/)

Comment: I also found the solutions you wrote above and thx for the code, but those ones fails when you resize the window with the mouse. that's why a need to use both left and right. Are you sure there is no way?

Comment: If you only animate the right side, it should fix the problem and still work as you resize the window (at least as good as the present design). [**See this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614700/html-on-a-responsive-mobile-version-of-site/28615119#28615119) for more information about "responsive" (re-sizeable) web site design.